# How do I make my program treat the first line as 'special'

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, if-statement, split

I am reading in a file containing many times that look like this `'22:28:28.373528'` over and over. But I am trying to find the first time listed with the regex expression and put it into my `$start_time` variable. The problem I keep having is that my program continues to overwrite the `$start_time` variable because it isn't treating the first line as 'special'. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks ahead!

```
my @header = split (' ',$_);
print OUTFILE "$linenum: @header\n\n";

if $_ =~ /^22:28/ {
        $start_time = $header[0];
    }
```

Comment: I assume you meant `many lines` when you said `many times`?

Comment: Thanks for the editing TLP, I was unaware of how to express those things you changed in the way you did. sorry. and no I meant 'times'. 22:28:28 is a time and there are many listed in the file I am using.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps using another word, such as "timestamps" might be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the program to update `$start_time` only if it isn't already set:

```
$start_time = undef;
if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) {
    $start_time = $header[0];
}
```

There's a little shorthand I like to use in Perl for setting variables only the first time:

```
if (/^22:28/) {
    $start_time ||= $header[0];
}
```

That translates to `$start_time || $start_time = $header[0]`, and means "if `$start_time` is false, then do `$start_time = $header[0]`".

Comment: WOO thank you your top piece worked for me very well! Now I have an $end_time variable and a final time from the file to grab. Would I use similar code? aside from the ^ anchor to $?

Comment: I don't see why not. Though if by "a final time" you mean the last time listed in the file, then overwriting the variable each time is exactly what you want to do there.

Comment: You can also use the "defined-or" operator `$start //= $header[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not show the code that controls your loop, which is a bit silly, considering you want to have a special case for the first loop iteration.

When you have a "first line" kind of thing, I often find that it is best to put that assignment before the main loop, so that we do not need to create a special case check inside the loop:

```
# reading file handle $fh line-by-line
my $first = <$fh>;
my @header = split ' ', $first;
my $start_time = $header[0];

while (<$fh>) { # read rest of file
    ...
```

If you slurp the file into an array, which is a (not recommended) common technique with new Perl users:

```
my @file = <$fh>;            # read whole file into array
my $first = shift @file;     # removing first line
# OR
my $first = $file[0];        # keep line

for my $line (@file) {       # read rest of file
    ...
```

The benefit of moving this assignment out of the loop is that it is more clear, and also you do not waste processing power checking if the value has already been assigned.

Comment: I never thought of that, that is very interesting way to do it!! I think i'm going to try that actually even though what I have works anyways hah. thanks!